# Simulate a crashing bash script

Tags: bash, exception

I'm trying to test a bash script that restarts it's child process when the child process has crashed.
How do I make a bash script crash on purpose?

(I'm trying to test the script that restarts the process)

Comment: What do you mean by "crash a bash script"?

Comment: I think to make it throw an exception that indicates some sort of fatal error. (I'm a novice bash user)

Comment: something like `ps -ef |grep "scriptname"|xargs kill` can help once you start the script

Comment: make sure there is no file named box.txt , then run `cat box.txt`. Or, run `bogus-command`. Or, make sure there is dir named nofolder, then run `ls -l nofolder`,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To exit a script while signaling an error, use:

```
exit 1
```

That exits with exit code `1`, indicating failure.  Other non-zero numbers can be used to signal different failure conditions.  `exit 0` signals success.

To throw an exception, use `kill`.  To issue the hangup signal, for example, from within a script, run:

```
kill -SIGHUP $$
```

To see the complete list of signals that can be generated, run:

```
kill -l
```

Answer (score 25):

Do you mean something like this?

```
# this simulates a script returning exit code of 1
sh -c 'exit 1'
```

Answer (score 3):

To complement [@John1024's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23418012/45375), here are two scripts that demonstrate the features discussed:

`worker`: A worker script that, when run, kills itself (its own process) after a specifiable period, in order to simulate a crash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

n=${1:-2}  # Default to 2 seconds

echo "worker: Will self-destruct in $n seconds..."

sleep $n

echo "worker: Self-destructing..."
kill $$
```

`monitor`: a script that invokes `worker` in the background, waits for its termination, reports the exit code, then restarts it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

workerScript='./worker'

# Loop that ensures that the worker script
# is launched and restarted after it terminates.
while true; do

  echo "monitor: Launching worker script in background..."
  "$workerScript" &

  # Wait for the worker script to terminate,
  # for whatever reason, and record its exit code.
  echo "monitor: Waiting for worker script to terminate..."
  # ${!} ($!) is the PID of the most recently started background command.
  # `wait` reports the specified process' exit code.
  wait ${!}; ec=$?  

  # Report worker's exit code and restart.
  echo "monitor: Worker script terminated with exit code $ec; restarting..."

done
```

Note:

- `kill` uses the `[SIG]TERM` signal by default, whose numerical value is `15` (see `kill -l`).
- In general, `bash` scripts terminated by a signal will report exit code `128 + <signal number>`.
- Therefore, using `kill` either without a signal specification or with `-TERM` results in exit code `143`; using `-HUP` (`-SIGHUP`) results in `129`.